# SPA - When to use Location Based or Internal State?

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

Hopefully this is not too opinionated but I am wondering if there are best practices regarding location-based SPAs and Internal based SPAs.

```
Internal based SPAs -  track state internally
Location-based SPAs - URL location / Sessions , etc
```

In one part of my site if a user pastes in the url the search results will show.

However if I should be doing it for areas like admin section.

For instance I am allow users to add inventory to this point

admin -> add new Inventory -> choose center -> choose subcategory -> add inventory.

This is pretty much the flow, however if I would make it location based then on the "add inventory page" I would have to set the

- company
- center
- subcategory

Which would require ajax requests to get all the data and basically every page I would have to do setting up data. It just seems like alot of work that every page has to be fully setup if they are coming from a url.

I am already using stuff like react-router to do my routing but in the end of the day I would to make sure that everything is always setup to the page can basically run standalone.

So maybe in some situations it would be better to somehow just redirect users back to the root of everything instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for resolving your problem.

Once authorized, you can set the `Provider` value to be the user or their permissions, then on each `ComponentDidMount` or `render()` or whatever lifecycle hook you choose, you can check the users permissions and then allow the functionalities based on that.

Context values persist throughout routing, so you won't have to worry about updating it all the time (although you probably should if your user has a timed session).

So it is fully possible and probably more effective to use a mix of both internal and location based state management.